# Is there a verb which describes the action of applying only minor changes to a sentence?

Tags: word-request

If I applied minor changes to a sentence, e.g. substituted two words in a ten-word one, or added a phrase halfway through, what would the verb which describes this action be?
My first thought was "rephrase" or "paraphrase" but neither seems to work since, as far as I can tell, they both indicate applying major changes which is not exactly what I am looking for.
Then I wondered if "reword" could be the verb but, again, does not seem to carry the intended meaning.

The context is: a saying that has been altered in a way which made it flexible and able to be used freely without sticking to the original structure.

Comment: [making minor change. :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always that old favorite: **tweaking.**

to make small adjustments to something, usually a machine, but editors and so forth do say and write to tweak a text, or article, etc.

Answer (score 3):

amend: make minor changes to (a text, piece of legislation, etc.) in order to make it fairer or more accurate, or to reflect changing circumstances.